# Angular2 Routerlink gives me an unexpected closing tag error

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I add the routerlink to my div tag, I get an error saying I've a closing div tag without one opening it ?

Here's the code with the error:

```
<div class="row products">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product" *ngFor="let product of categoryProducts?.Products">
        <div [routerLink]=['/product','product.Sku'] >
            <div class="product-image">
                <img class="col-lg-12" src="{{product.Urls[0]}}"/>
            </div>
            <div>{{product.Sku}}</div>
            <div>&#8364;{{product.Price}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I remove the routerlink from the div, it works.

Here's the error

```
Unexpected closing tag "div" ("
        </div>
    </div>
[ERROR ->]</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the quotes are missing `[routerLink]="['/product','product.Sku']"`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!